# php different logic based on request is ajax or normal

Tags: php, ajax

suppose i have a php database connection file. Consider two cases if there is an connection error :

1. If request is a normal request (not ajax) then i would simply echo a message and exit.
2. If request is a ajax request then i have to use json encode to send status and msg to client side js.

How can i separate the logic for above code, or how is this normally handled by you guys.

Consider another case : 
If a login in session is expired :

1. If request is a normal request (not ajax) then i would simply use header('location: login.php');
2. If request is a ajax request then ? **(should i need to send a status code to client side and then use window.location )**

Comment: What about using POST method in ajax and checking it in php code?

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')

Answer (score 0):

Please use Below Code:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{    
  echo "Ajax Request";
}
else{
  echo "Not an Ajax Request";
}
```